# Simple click event

Tags: actionscript-3, click, mouseevent

I don't know why I can't figure out this problem that is really basics !! (sometimes the brain is tired I guess).

I've got a movieclip with a guitar string. 
I want the string to move everytime I click on it.

I've created a movie clip with 2 lables. the first = non movement, the second = movement. 
I've placed in the second one a stop(); action. (in order to stop the loop)

I've put this code :

```
stringOne.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, accord1, false, 0, true);

public function accord1(e:MouseEvent):void{
            var stringOne;
            trace("DING");
            stringOne.gotoAndStop("first");
        }
```

It works but, of course, it only play the string movement at the first click.

Do you know how I could play the string movement EVERYTIME that I click on the string ?

Thank you very much and sorry for this easy question (little ashamed)..,

### EDIT

Ah ! It seems to work with goToAndPlay !

```
if (stringOne.currentLabel=="premier") {
     stringOne.gotoAndStop("default");
            } else {
     stringOne.gotoAndStop("first");
}
```

Just a thing, I have to click twice..

```
(one click = the string vibrate (label2)) 
(one click again = the string does nothing (going to label 1)) 
(one click again = the string vibrate (label 2))
```

Is there anyway to automatically skip the 2nd click (the one that tells the string to go back at label 1), and let do the code like : - When animation of label 2 is finished, automatically go back to label 1 ? –

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, the "movement" label of the string is some sort of animation?

It seems to me what you want in your "guitar string" movieClip is, on the last frame of the timeline animation for "movement", a script that says gotoAndStop('non movement').  The click handler should gotoAndPlay('movement').

Then, when the string 'movement' animation is finished, it will reset itself, so that the next time you click it will play again.

So, your original code is fine (before the edit;  but remove the "var stringOne;" since that will break the reference to stringOne).  The only thing you need to add is a script in the timeline on the last frame of the movement animation ("first" label?) that says gotoAndPlay("default") (assuming default is the 'non movement' label).  You may need a stop() in the timeline frame for "default".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've found an other way, instead of mouse click I've used mouse down for going to frame 2 and mouse up for going to frame 1

Comment: It seems to me what I described is better than using mouseDown, since that will change the interactivity of your project.  The way you're now doing it, I'd think you have to keep the mouse down while the string plays-- mouseUp and it will instantly stop, even in the middle of the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that :

```
stage.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onStageClick);

protected function onStageClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    switch( event.target )
    {
        case stringOne:
            trace("String one stuff");
            break;
        case stringTwo:
            trace("String 2 stuff");
            break;
    }
}
```

Or add your movieClip into a Sprite and listen click event on the Sprite and not on the MovieClips.

Comment: Don't really understand. Where do I put the animation ? When the code is going to get that ? I've tried the code, If I click on the first string it traces "String one stuff" (perfect, so it reconize that I clicked on it), but I want the string to vibrate each time I click on the string. Where do I put the animation, and the code that 's gonna find the animation ?

Comment: Did you tried to replace trace("String one stuff"); by event.target.gotoAndStop("first"); ?

Comment: Yes I have. Here's whats happening : http://ul.to/87b1vw12  As you can see, the vibration of the strings don't stop... I'd like them to vibrate each time I click.. Do you know what could be the problem ?

Comment: Ah ! It seems to work with goToAndPlay !
Just a thing, I have to click twice..
(one click = the string vibrate (frame2))
(one click again = the string does nothing (going to frame 1))
(one click again = the string vibrate (frame2))
 
Is there anyway to automatically skip the 2nd click (the one that tells the string to go back at frame1), and let do the code like :
 
- When animation of frame 2 is finished, automatically go back to frame 1
 
?

Comment: Nobody know how I could tell the code to automatically go back to label 1 at the end of  the animation of label 2 ? (not frame as I said before, but "labels")
 
I've been on it all day and I can't figure it out !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer. I've found an other way, instead of mouse click I've used mouse down for going to frame 2 and mouse up for going to frame 1